# It is possible to write open subsets in the form $\Omega=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^N:g(x)>0 \}$

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, continuity

> Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$. Do we have in general the existence of a continuous function $g:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
>   $$\Omega=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^N:g(x)>0 \}$$

Comment: The distance to the complement does the job.

Comment: The terminology for this is that open subsets of $\Bbb R^N$ are "functionally open".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: If $\Omega\neq \mathbb R^N$
 $$g:x\mapsto d(x,\Omega^c)$$

and If $\Omega=\mathbb R^N$
$$g(x)  = \|x\| +1$$