# Existence of continuous function $f$ on $\Bbb R$ which vanishes exactly on $A\subset \Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

> **Question** For any closed subset $A \subset \Bbb R$, does there exist a continuous function $f$ on $\Bbb R$ which vanishes exactly on $A$?

If we take $A=[a,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,a]$ or $\{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\}$ or $\bigcup_{i=1}^{k} [a_i,b_i]$, then indeed we can have such a continuous function. But when I thought about cantor set or the set $\{\frac 1n : n \in \Bbb N\} \cup \{0\}$, which are closed in $\Bbb R$, I couldn't think of a continuous map vanishing exactly at these two sets.

How should I go about this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Yes there exists more than continuous  **since A is closed**, just take$$x\mapsto f(x) =\color{blue}{d(x,A) =\inf\{|x-y|: y\in A\}~~~~\text{Which is even Lipschitz function }}$$
>   Since we konw that $$d(x,B)= 0\Longleftrightarrow x\in\bar B$$

It follow from triangular inequality that:

$$\color{red}{|f(x)-f(y)|\le |x-y|}$$

Also [see this:](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2447582) from here [It is possible to write open subsets in the form $\Omega=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^N:g(x)>0 \}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2447570/it-is-possible-to-write-open-subsets-in-the-form-omega-x-in-mathbbrngx)

Comment: The funny thing is that I knew this function and it's properties but it didn't "click" me. :(

Comment: min, even, suffices!

Comment: @PeteCaradonna min suffices when A is compact

Comment: @GuyFsone Is boundedness required?  Somehow, if $A$ is unbounded, the 'tails' of $A$  would seem irrelevant.

Comment: @PeteCaradonna just assume that $A=\Bbb N$ then can you have a mean? the OP did not assume the boundedness of A

Comment: @GuyFsone I'm not sure I follow what you mean by 'have a mean.'  If $A = \mathbb{N}$ then $d(x,A) := \textrm{min}\{|x-y| \; : \; y \in \mathbb{N}\}$ suffices.

Comment: @PeteCaradonna Yes understand that . But still woundaring  whether mean always exists when A is not compact

Comment: @GuyFsone I think all that's needed is non-emptiness.  If $A$ non-empty, then pick arbitrary $a \in A$.  Let $B_{|x-a|}(x)$ be the ball of radius $|x-a|$ about $x$, and define: $f(x) = d_a(x, A) = \textrm{min}\{|x-y| : y \in \textrm{cl}B_{|x-a|}(x) \cap A\}$.  Moverover it is independent of the choice of $a$ and for all $a \in A$, $d_a(x,A)$ should coincide with your $d(x,A)$.

Comment: @PeteCaradonna you are right thanks